# Writing Python numpy arrays to .mat file

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, dictionary

I have a series of numpy arrays that I want to save in a .mat file so that I can plot the data later. (I don't want to use Pickle because my actual program is much more complicated and has more than 2 arrays.) My MWE is:

```
import numpy as np
import mat4py as m4p

x = np.array([1,20,0.4,0.5,9,8.8])
y = np.array([0.3,0.6,1,1,0.01,0.7])

data = {'x': x,
        'y': y}
m4p.savemat('datafile.mat', data)
```

but I get an error `ValueError: Only dicts, two dimensional numeric, and char arrays are currently supported`.

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Try scipy's `savemat`. `from scipy import io`; io.savemat(...)`. But it will save your arrays as 2d since that is what matlab expects.

Comment: `mat4py ` works with lists not numpy arrays.  scipy is built on numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert `numpy` arrays into `python` lists.

You can create `x` and `y` like:

```
x = [1,20,0.4,0.5,9,8.8]
y = [0.3,0.6,1,1,0.01,0.7]
```

Now `data` will contain `python` lists and `m4p.savemat('datafile.mat', data)` will work.

**Edit:**

If you need to work with numpy arrays, you can convert them on-the-fly when creating `data` as follows:

```
data = {'x' : x.tolist(), 'y' : y.tolist()}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
In [853]: from scipy import io
In [854]: x = np.array([1,20,0.4,0.5,9,8.8])
     ...: y = np.array([0.3,0.6,1,1,0.01,0.7])
     ...: 
In [855]: data={'x':x, 'y':y}
In [856]: io.savemat('test.mat',data)
In [857]: io.loadmat('test.mat')
Out[857]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Sun Nov 27 09:30:35 2016',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'x': array([[  1. ,  20. ,   0.4,   0.5,   9. ,   8.8]]),
 'y': array([[ 0.3 ,  0.6 ,  1.  ,  1.  ,  0.01,  0.7 ]])}
```

For MATLAB compatibility the arrays have been turned into 2d orderF arrays.

`h5py` is another option.  Newer Matlab versions use the HDF5 format, providing greater compatibility with other languages.

`np.savez` can save a dictionary of arrays without modifying them:

```
In [881]: data={'x':x, 'y':y,'xy':np.array((x,y))}
In [882]: np.savez('test',**data)
In [883]: D=np.load('test.npz')
In [884]: D.keys()
Out[884]: ['y', 'x', 'xy']
In [885]: D['xy']
Out[885]: 
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+01,   4.00000000e-01,
          5.00000000e-01,   9.00000000e+00,   8.80000000e+00],
       [  3.00000000e-01,   6.00000000e-01,   1.00000000e+00,
          1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e-02,   7.00000000e-01]])
```

`D` is an `NPZFile` object, which is a lazy loader.  So it does not dump all the arrays directly into memory.  You access them by key name.

Comment: I'm interested in the `h5py` option to write to an already existing .mat file created with MATLAB.  Is this possible?  I can't quite see how to structure the arrays from this answer.

Comment: @villaa, it should be straight forward to load the arrays as shown above.   Writing arrays to a `HDF5` file is documented in the `h5py` docs.  The only nuance is that `order F` files will be saved as `order C`.  I'd suggest you read up on `h5py`, try some simple cases, and ask a new question if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to interface to Matlab, there really is no reason to use `mat4py`. 
You can use the build-in [`numpy.save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save) for single arrays, or [`numpy.savez()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) for multiple arrays. For large arrays use [`numpy.savez_compressed()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed).

Comment: That looks nice. I'm currently using Spyder - is there a shortcut for saving *everything* on my workspace so that I won't have to specify each variable, array, etc in `savez_compressed`?

Comment: I cant follow you. Spyder can save all your .py files. Here, we're talking about saving one or several arrays into a file during runtime of the script in python.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest I'll eventually be running this code on HPC clusters where I can't save variables using the Spyder GUI. What I meant was, is there a way to save the workspace using `savez_compressed` without specifying each variable?

Comment: @MedullaOblongata I am not aware of any such option. It wouldn't make much sense in my opinion anyways, since you normally do not want all your workspace saved but only the result of your calculations. Keeping track of then saved variables also makes sense, to later be able to recover them.